# Задача с семафорами — железная дорога

Tags: алгоритм, многопоточность, семафоры

Дана такая задача:

> Железная дорога, соединяющая города A и B, имеет участок с одним
>   путем. Пусть движение поездов из A в B и из B в A – процессы.
>   Используя семафоры, запрограммировать движение поездов таким образом,
>   чтобы в любой момент времени по единственному пути поезда двигались
>   только в одном направлении. Рассмотреть проблему бесконечного
>   ожидания, варианты ее решения

Дополнительные ограничения: нельзя использовать активное ожидание, включая `sleep` и проверку в цикле, нельзя просто ограничить «доступ к дороге» одному потоку — несколько поездов в одном направлении могут двигаться вместе, скорость их одинаковая, длина каждого поезда нулевая.

Моё решение (`w_` — означает west, приведен код только для движения в одну сторону — с запада на восток, в другую сторону — симметрично)

```
w_turnstile=Semaphore(1);
w_mutex=Semaphore(1);
lock=Semaphore(1);
w_counter=0;

void w_thread()
{
     P(w_turnstile);
     V(w_turnstile);

     P(w_mutex);
     w_counter++;
     if(w_counter==1){
          P(e_turnstile);
          P(lock);
          V(e_turnstile);
     }
     V(w_mutex);

     //движение поезда

     P(w_mutex);
     w_counter--;
     if(w_counter==0){
          V(lock);
     }
     V(v_mutex);
}
```

Бесконечное ожидание отсутствует из-за того, что когда появляется, допустим, поезд c востока на запад, он уменьшает значение семафора `w_turnstile`, и новые поезда с запада на восток ждут на этом семафоре и не могут увеличить счётчик `w_counter`, а старые поезда прийти могут. То есть в итоге семафор `lock` будет отпущен, когда все старые поезда с запада на восток придут.

Есть ли ошибки в этом решении и есть ли более оптимальное решение?